# On the linear dependence of three coplanar vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, coordinate-systems

The general consensus seems to be that any three coplanar vectors are linearly dependent. [Here's](https://portal.tpu.ru/SHARED/k/KONVAL/Sites/English_sites/V/v_LinearDepP_m.htm#:%7E:text=Therefore%2C%20a%20set%20of%20three%20coplanar%20vectors%20is%20linear%20dependent.&text=Note%20that%20any%20two%20vectors,as%20a%20linear%20combination%20of%20.) one source that says so.

However, considering three vectors, of which two are collinear and the third non-collinear to either of them, isn't that false? I've tried it with $\hat i,2 \hat i$ and $ \hat i+ \hat j$. They seem to be linearly independent.

Is it something about the definition that makes this case not applicable to the general statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Definitions:

   - Vectors are **coplanar** iff they are parallel to some plane. So, in two    dimensions, all vectors are coplanar.
   - A set of vectors is **linearly dependent** iff some non-trivial linear    combination of some of its members equals the zero vector.
     <sup>(A trivial linear combination means that the coefficients are
     all 0.)</sup>
2. As shown by Chris in another answer, your three given coplanar vectors are
   indeed linearly dependent.
3. A consequence of the second definition above is that if a set of
   vectors contains a linearly dependent pair (i.e., a collinear pair),
   then the entire set must also be linearly dependent.

Answer (score 2):

A plane is two-dimensional, so any *three* vectors in a plane are dependent.

In your example, they are dependent since $2\hat i=2\cdot\hat i$.  In other words, we get the non-trivial linear combination $(-2)\cdot\hat i+(1)\cdot2\hat i+0\cdot(\hat i+\hat j)=0$.

Comment: Do you mean $\hat i$ and $\hat 2i$ can't be considered as two coplanar vectors? [Wikipedia's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coplanarity) article on them doesn't specify that.

Comment: They're coplanar:  they're collinear.  Collinear implies coplanar, doesn't it?

Comment: Of course, _any_ two vectors are coplanar, since they span at most a plane.  A line is contained in a plane.  Now on the other hand, _three_ vectors are not necessarily coplanar.  And if they are they are dependent.

Comment: Oh. 'Multiplying by coefficients *not all* 0'. I hadn't considered multiplying one by 0. Got it, thanks.

Comment: That's right.   I hoped you would catch that.

Comment: This answers my specific question really well, but Ryan's is a general overview, so I went with that, hope you don't mind.

Comment: No problem Harry.  Got ya.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the statement says any three coplanar vectors that are linearly **dependent** are coplanar.